# What is the Groovy truth of an empty closure?

Tags: groovy, closures

I am trying to predict the behavior of this code in Groovy

```
userList.find { }
```

[.find documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#find(groovy.lang.Closure))

When the `find` method is invoked and passed a closure it returns the first element that  evaluates the closure into Groovies understanding of `true`.
When the `find` method is called without any parameters it returns the first object in the list that matches `true` according to Groovy truth.

What happens if an empty closure is used?

1. Will it evaluate to true and thus the first element of the list is returned?
2. Will it always evaluate to false and after iterating over the list `null` is returned?
3. Will it be behave like `.find()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Groovy Closures Formal Definition](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures+-+Formal+Definition) ([Alternative Source](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_calling_a_closure)):

> Closures always have a return value. The value may be specified via one or more explicit return statement in the closure body, or as the value of the last executed statement if return is not explicitly specified. If the last executed statement has no value (for example, if the last statement is a call to a void method), then null is returned.

And from [Groovy Truth](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#Groovy-Truth)

> **Object references**
>   Non-null object references are coerced to true.
>   ...
>
> ```
> assert !null
> ```

That suggests to me that the truth of the return value of an empty closure is always false, so `find` will never find anything, and thus presumably return `null`.

Comment: So the answers to the three questions are: (1) "No", (2) "Yes", (3) "No, since `.find()` uses the 'identity closure' `{it}`. Thus, `userList.find()` will find the first 'truthy' value in `userList`, while `userList.find{}` will never find anything."

Comment: thank you for summarizing. Jon's clarification on the groovy truth made clear that the answer to (2) is  "Yes" and due to my formulation of (2), the answer to (3) must be "No".

Comment: So you should probably give him his +15 up-check. He's been waiting for it very patiently. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

there is no definition of "empty closure" only if you delegate this closure to a Map, then the Map keeps empty :

```
​Map closureToMap(Closure c, Map attrs=[:]) {
    c.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    c.delegate = attrs
    c()
    return attrs
  }

def myEmptyClosure = {}
assert closureToMap(myEmptyClosure).isEmpty()
```